# How do I put params into this line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a button, that changes Object's boolean value.

Have this line:

```
= button_to 'Subscribe Back', candidate_subscriber_path(subscriber), method: :patch
```

Which makes this request:

```
{"_method"=>"patch", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"candidate/subscribers", "id"=>"2"}
```

I need it to send these attributes:

```
subscribed: true
```

Have no idea where to put them. Do you have any clues?

Tried:

```
= button_to 'Subscribe Back', candidate_subscriber_path(subscriber, subscribed: true), method: :patch
= button_to 'Subscribe Back', { controller: 'subscribers', action: 'update', id: subscriber.id, subscribed: false }, method: :patch
```

Couple other options.

The only option that works for me is:

```
= simple_form_for :subscriber, url: candidate_subscriber_path(subscriber),
                                                   html: { method: :patch } do |f|
  = f.input :subscribed, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: '1' }
  = f.button :submit, 'Subscribe Back'
```

Comment: Have a look at this; same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363153/rails3-pass-arbitrary-parameters-via-button-to

Comment: you can add "subscribed: true" inside = simple_form_for :subscriber, url: candidate_subscriber_path(subscriber, subscribed:true )

Comment: want to know why some people suggested button_to )

Answer (score 1):

the way that I would approach it would be to create an action specifically for that.

add to your candidate route -

```
patch "/resubscribe/:id", to: "candidate/subscribers#resub"
```

then in the controller

```
def resub
  user = YourModel.find(params[:id])
  user.update_attributes( subscribed: true )
end
```

then just send that path to your button

Comment: yeah that breaks CRUD