# Product id shows nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

commerce project with ROR and Mongodb I just wanted to add the product to a cart, cart is getting its session value but product is not getting the product_id.

***Line_items_controller***

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
product=Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product) #bawaal
#@line_item.cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) || Cart.new
#@line_item.product =Product.find(params["line_item"]["product"])
#@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
      notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

**store#index.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(line_items: {product_id: @product}), remote: true, method: :post %>
```

**cart model**

```
    def add_product(product_id)
     current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id: product_id)

if current_item
    current_item.quantity +=1
else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    #current_item = current_item.product.price
end
current_item
end
```

**application controller**

```
    def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id].blank?
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    else
    cart = Cart.find session[:cart_id]
    end
    cart

  end
```

thanks please help me !!!!!

Comment: Where are you trying to access `product id` and post your params as well.

Comment: It is in line_item_controller and my params after using raise "#{params.inspect}" {"authenticity_token"=>"Z3MgeKE2TI9HyiOwhHZAsgjPZAAUdFWdtbNHCDYdIaY=", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"}

Answer (score 0):

On SO, it generally helps to be as specific as possible (IE showing us an `error log` etc)

--

**product_id**

When you ask whether `product_id` cannot be set, there are several times you select this in your provided code, especially here:

```
#app/views/store/index.html.erb
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(line_items: {product_id: @product}), remote: true, method: :post %>
```

I believe the issue will likely be with your sending of your params to the controller with the link above. If you have us the `logs` for this, it would be amazing, but lacking that, I want to highlight this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :line_items #-> POST domain.com/line_items = create

#app/views/store/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag line_items_path do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "product_id", @product.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add To Cart" %>
<% end %>

or

<%= button_to "Add To Cart", line_items_path(@product) %>
```

This should give you the ability to add as many line items as you wish to your cart - however, seeing your `logs` will give us a much better chance of helping you to fix!

--

**Update**

The problem you have is you're sending through a `product_id` param to your controller.

As your controller's `create` method uses `find`:

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find params[:product_id]
end
```

Your params are as follows:

{"authenticity_token"=>"Z3MgeKE2TI9HyiOwhHZAsgjPZAAUdFWdtbNHCDYdIaY=", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"}

Notice how you have not passed the record you require?

This is a standard issue with `button_to` - we tend to use `link_to` to make this work better. It seems [this answer says the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363153/rails3-pass-arbitrary-parameters-via-button-to) too

Perhaps you'd want to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Add To Cart", line_items_path(@product), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Logs:Started POST "/line_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-09 14:55:20 +0530
Processing by LineItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Z3MgeKE2TI9HyiOwhHZAsgjPZAAUdFWdtbNHCDYdIa
Y="}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

RuntimeError - {"authenticity_token"=>"Z3MgeKE2TI9HyiOwhHZAsgjPZAAUdFWdtbNHCDYdI
aY=", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"}:
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:33:in `create'

Comment: Looks like you're not passing your `product_id` param!! Is this after you click your button?

Comment: yes this error generates after clicking the addtocart button my params are {"authenticity_token"=>"Z3MgeKE2TI9HyiOwhHZAsgjPZAAUdFWdtbNHCDYdIaY=", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"}

Comment: sorry it did not work link_to is used for get method while button_to is for post i need to to create the line_item thats why it is butto_to

Comment: will u please explain me the flow it would be really great for me to know when i click the button where it starts and where it ends

Answer (score 0):

The cart shoud not have product id. It is having association with link_item. Try in rails console this, Cart.last.link_item it will show u the last added product.